# Is there a way to overwrite the devise sessions controller create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, before-filter

I want to know if there is a way to overwrite the devise sessions controller create action within the application controller. So i have this code

```
  def check_concurrent_session
    if is_already_logged_in?
      flash[:error] = "We're sorry, you can't login to two places concurrently."
      sign_out_and_redirect(current_user)
    end
  end
```

and I need this to run everywhere on the site other then create action in the devise sessions controller..

So i have a before_filter on the application controller, but can i exclude a contoller like

```
before_filter :check_concurrent_session, :except => ["somecontoller"]
```

obviously this is wrong but you get the idea. I know i can create my own sessions controller and inherit from devise but i want to know if this is possible to do this from within application controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
before_filter :check_concurrent_session

def check_concurrent_session
  return if controller_name == 'some_controller'
  if is_already_logged_in?
    flash[:error] = "We're sorry, you can't login to two places concurrently."
    sign_out_and_redirect(current_user)
  end
end
```

Comment: that was exactly what i needed....so simple..cant believe i didnt think of that ...thanks

Comment: I have one small doubt this method  check_concurrent_session is it custom or given by devise? I am trying to search in the devise source code I couldn't find the definition of this method

Answer (score 1):

In `application.rb`

```
module XXX
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...

    config.to_prepare do
      Devise::SessionsController.skip_before_filter :check_concurrent_session
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thats nice to know that you can overwrite anything in the application.rb thanks again